# Bug in java.time.Duration

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I need to parse [Durations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) from strings. Java 8 provide a method for that taking the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard as a basis:

```
Duration.parse("p10d"); // parses as ten days
Duration.parse("pt1h"); // parses as one hour
```

As the standard states that "it is permitted to omit the 'T' character by mutual agreement" some of the Javadoc examples of [Durations.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) leave out the `T`. According to them, the following expression should parse as "-6 hours and +3 minutes":

```
"P-6H3M"
```

But I found that all expressions ommitting the `T` throw a `DateTimeParseException`. Is that a bug in the `parse()` method or am I missing something?

Comment: I think the quote about the "mutual agreement" only refers to the "T" in the combined date-time representation, not the Duration representation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) of `parse()`:

> The ASCII letter "T" **must** occur before the first occurrence, if any, of an **hour**, **minute** or **second** section.

That means you have to include `T` whenever you use `H`, `M`, or `S`.

---

The examples are wrong though:

```
"P-6H3M"    -- parses as "-6 hours and +3 minutes"
"-P6H3M"    -- parses as "-6 hours and -3 minutes"
"-P-6H+3M"  -- parses as "+6 hours and -3 minutes"
```

Comment: Personally I'd love to see the method accepting strings like "p1d1h" for 25 hours (no `T`). Duration strings in configuration files would be very easy to read (e. g. "1d1h"): Prepending a `P` is easy, but adding a `T` somewhere in the string is not trivial. Just imagine the method starts accepting weeks and nanoseconds in Java 9. Where would you have to put the `T` in a string "1w1m1s1n".

Comment: @steffen `T` means `time sections`, so it should be always before `H` and after `D`.

Comment: Yes, but both H and D may be omitted.

Comment: The "T" is required because "M" is used for months and minutes

Comment: @JodaStephen You are 100% right in regards to the standard. `M` in a duration however always refers to minutes since it's a time based class (in contrast to [Period](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)).

Comment: @steffen Since Duration and Period use the same input format, the same input string should mean the same thing to both of them.

Comment: @Brilliand The only (!) input which is accepted by both Duration and Period at the same time is actually "PnD" (n=number of days) and even this input doesn't mean the same thing! (See class description of Period for details.) Nevertheless I do agree that both input strings should base on the one standard.

Comment: I've added to a JDK bug to try and get the doc bug fixed.

Answer (score 12):

The regular expression used by `Duration.parse` is:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("([-+]?)P(?:([-+]?[0-9]+)D)?" +
                "(T(?:([-+]?[0-9]+)H)?(?:([-+]?[0-9]+)M)?(?:([-+]?[0-9]+)(?:[.,]([0-9]{0,9}))?S)?)?",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

The input `P-6H3M` is not matched by this regular expression. If it is changed to

```
"(T?(?:([-+]?[ ...
```

in the fourth line (note the `?` after the `T`), the examples match (test it on http://regexpal.com/).

So it looks like you have found an inconsistency between code and JavaDoc.

Comment: Why is this a bug? First, the reference OP made to the standard pertains to the date+time representation, not to duration representation. Second, mutual agreement means that the JDK may decide not to be an agreeing party.

Comment: You are completely right. The interpretation the OP made of the standard probably is wrong.

Comment: Regex : http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/Duration.java#l151